# Compiling multiple files in Java using TextPad

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to compile my HelloApp2 file using TextPad, but it references another class in a different file in the greeter class. I keep getting errors that say that Greeter is not recognized. DOes anybody know how to do this in TextPad?

HelloApp2.java:

```
public class HelloApp2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Greeter myGreeterObject = new Greeter();
    myGreeterObject.sayHello();
}
}
```

Greeter.java:

```
public class Greeter
{
public void sayHello()
{
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling Greeter.java first and then compiling HelloApp2.java??

Comment: Yes, I did. And I just tried again. It still points to errors at Greeter and new Greeter() in HelloeApp2

Comment: Then you should go through this http://www.marquette.edu/mscs/resources-textpad-java.shtml May it help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to import that class

```
import Greeter.*;
```

only if you have that file in the same folder where your main program is located

or else you have to specify the package details like

```
import package.Greeter.*;
```

Comment: NO!!!! The `import Greeter.*` is wrong. You use that to specify sub-members of packages.

Comment: Yes @JasonS we are using the methods in the class i.e a member function
so I suppose it is correct

Comment: The use of `import` for methods is only correct for using static class methods. Instance methods can't be used that way. If you want to import a class, which is the aim of the original question here, then you should be just doing `import Greeter`.

Answer (score 0):

If `HelloApp2` references `Greeter`, you need to put an `import Greeter` into the top of `HelloApp2.java`.

```
import Greeter

public class HelloApp2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Greeter myGreeterObject = new Greeter();
        myGreeterObject.sayHello();
    }
}
```

See the [java docs about importing packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

This has nothing to do with TextPad... I would highly recommend using an IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ Community Edition which are free and will save you loads of time writing, building, and debugging your Java software.

Comment: Oh. Ok im brand new to java. What would that look like?

Comment: Oh man! I downloaded NetBeans. It is way easier to work with! Thank you for the advice!

Comment: IntelliJ may be even better. I haven't used it myself but I've heard really good things about JetBrains, and their PyCharm IDE is awesome, much easier to use than Eclipse + PyDev.