# Java for dummies multi file exercise

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm having the same problem as this person [Compiling multiple files in Java using TextPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334683/compiling-multiple-files-in-java-using-textpad)

If the question was answered before I didn't understand, tried many variations of importing Greeter, none seem to work. Getting really discouraged that I can't understand one of the first exercises in the java for dummies book.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is straight-forward if both files are in the same directory and should work without problems.

```
javac Greeter.java HelloApp.java      # Compile
java HelloApp                         # Execute
```

---

*HelloApp.java*

```
public class HelloApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeter myGreeterObject = new Greeter();
        myGreeterObject.sayHello();
    }
}
```

*Greeter.java*

```
public class Greeter {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiling them together seemed to help, Helloapp seemed to compile for the first time, but there's a new new error when I tried to run it: java.lang.classnotfoundexception